# Create a Json Epoch string

Tags: c#, json

I'm working with a third-party API, which requires me to format a date into a 'Json epoch format'.

I'm using c# and converting a class to Json using NewtonSoft's `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method.

The documentation example show the output like this:

`"DateOfBirth":"\/Date(1373388747000)\/"`

I've created a small extension method to do this:

```
public static string JsonEpoch(this DateTime @this)
{
    return $"\/Date({new DateTimeOffset(@this).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()})\/";
}
```

However, this does't work because of an unrecognized escape sequence.

Despite using different methods to escape it, I still can get the output right - one `'\'` before the `'/'`.

These don't work.

- $@"/Date({new DateTimeOffset(@this).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()})/";
- using two slashes (I can show here because editor removes one);

I'm sure it's simple but can't think how to get it sorted.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm

Comment: Brilliant - just what I needed.